# value registerAsTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

i am running below code in Zeppelin 0.7

```
%spark 
//val sc: SparkContext // An existing SparkContext.
sc
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val people = sqlContext.jsonFile("/Users/asdf/Desktop/people.json")
people.printSchema()
people.show()
people.select("name").show()
people.toDF().registerAsTable("people")
```

Its working till `people.select("name").show()` but throws error at last line, below is the error:

```
 +-------+
 |   name|
 +-------+
 |Michael|
 |   Andy|
 | Justin|
 +-------+

<console>:230: error: value registerAsTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
          people.toDF().registerAsTable("people")
```

asper my knowledge i imported all required and converted it to df before registering it as table. what am i missing here?

Comment: try registerAsTempTable("people")

Comment: No use with that aswell btw its `registerTempTable("people")`

Comment: try createOrReplaceTempView("people"), in spark 2.0 there is change in api

Comment: same error with `createOrReplaceTempView("people")`. It worked when i gave `registerTempTable("people")` but now i am unable to query people table. it says `no such table table`

Comment: i have spark 2.0 in my local system and zeppelin also has spark 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me, the issue was with Zeppelin that we should not create a SQLContext Zeppelin provides its own.

```
%spark 
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

val people = sqlContext.jsonFile("/Users/asdf/Desktop/people.json")
people.printSchema()
people.show()
people.select("name").show()
people.toDF().registerTempTable("people")
```

Then above created Temp table can be used to Query for interactive charts in `%sql` notebook of Zeppelin

Answer (score 1):

Add following two lines after line "people.select("name").show()"

```
people.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("people")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from people").show()
```

Though spark version is displayed in spark-shell during startup you can check the version using below command.

```
sc.version
```